# Proving that $\forall X\in U\setminus\{0\}, f(X)\neq X$ if $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $Df(0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm having some trouble with the following question:

> Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ be a function of class $C^1$ such that $f(0)=0$. Prove that if $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $Df(0)$, then there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $0$ such that, $$\forall X\in U\setminus\{0\}, f(X)\neq X$$

I know that the linear map $Df(0)$ is the linear map that better approximates the behavior of the function $f$ near the point $0$. And because $Df(0)$ doesn't have 1 as eigenvalue this means that this linear map either contracts expands or rotates space, and I think that's why $\forall X\in U\setminus\{0\}, f(X)\neq X$.

The thing is that this is only my intuition and I'm not being able to formalize this on a proof, how can this be done?

Until this point, we've only learned the Banach fixed point theorem, the inverse and implicit function theorem, and all the basic results about partial derivatives, total derivatives, jacobian matrices, and gradients. How can this be done?

Comment: Apply the inverse function theorem to $g(X) = f(X) -X$. This function has an invertible jacobian at $0$, and is thus one-to-one on a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: Why is $det(J(g)(0))\neq 0$? Isn't $J(g)(0) = J(f)(0) - Id_n$? @User8128

Comment: And how does that use the fact that 1 is not an eigenvalue of $Df(0)$?@User8128

Comment: $J(f)(0)$ does not have 1 as an eigenvalue. So what do you know about the eigenvalues of $J(f)(0) - \text{Id}_n$?

Comment: 0 is not an eigenvalue? @User8128